# Tools Automation as micro service

Tags: api, rest, microservices

I am thinking to build a micro services architecture for a set of tools.

Each tool have separate API implemented, exposed. They are deployed in their dedicated VMs.
Let's say, I've 3 tools.

1. Tool1 with Features are implemented and exposed as API1, API2, API3 in VM1
2. Tool2 with Features are implemented and exposed as API1, API2, API3, API4 in VM2
3. Tool3 with Features are implemented and exposed as API1, API2, API3, API4, API5 in VM3

I am planning to manage all tools from a centralised place (VM4). as a Micro Service API server.
Each tool features will be called something like,

- http://<host_of_VM4>/tool1/callapi1
- http://<host_of_VM4>/tool1/callapi2
- http://<host_of_VM4>/tool2/callapi3
- http://<host_of_VM4>/tool3/callapi5

So, the API implementation in VM4 will call the external API, which is in its corresponding tools server (either in VM1 / VM2 / VM3 ,..etc)

My Qn.

1. Is this a good approach to integrate all tools within a single API server, even though each tool has separate API implementation in their dedicated VMs.
2. If yes, How can I integrate all tools in a single place .?
   a) Do I need to call the tool APIs from the new Micro service . ?
   b) Or, do I need to have the entire source of all tool APIs within the new server. ?
3. Do I really need micro service design for this ,. ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I integrate all tools in a single place .?

One option is to use a reverse proxy on VM4. Otherwise, not clear how you're forwarding those requests

Other option is creating a GraphQL API instead of exposing URL routes

> do I need to have the entire source of all tool APIs within the new server. ?

I guess that depends how they run, but if HTTP is your communication channel, then no

> Do I really need micro service design for this

I would consider this distributed computing, not microservices. Plenty of organization combine multiple api calls between various internal services before "microservices" became popularized